# Is there a special utility box for installing a power outlet when the wall is tiled?

Tags: receptacle, tile

I watched [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/aOxBqHNeOQ8?t=854) showing how to cut the power outlet opening in tiles.

The guy mentioned he is not making the holes required to attach the user facing plate because he is buying a special utility box that does not require that. What is he referring to ?

Comment: With most outlets/switches the facing plate screws into the outlet/switch itself, not the box or wall, no special/extra holes need to be drilled/made.  Will need to know more about the power outlet and box you mentioned.

Comment: If this is for a GFCI outlet or if you're using "decora" outlets/switches then  you need to account for the screws that secure the faceplate.

Comment: Including a screen shot of the box in question would help a lot.

Comment: I am not there yet, and I have nothing special for that box but here is the video where the guy is mentioning it https://youtu.be/aOxBqHNeOQ8?t=854 , he is also showing the cuts he is not going to cut because of that "special" box you can buy. "Link in the description" but I am not seeing the link hence the ask here

Comment: Hey guys you asked for the info, I gave you what I had ...the source of info , does anybody know what he is talking about?

Comment: Those notches he did not cut are usually used for the screws(long one inch) for an outlet/switch to screw onto the box(not a face plate).  Imagine the boxes he uses are higher and have the screw holes on the inside instead of the outside.

Comment: Ugh. I despise youtube ‘experts’ who claim to be teaching beginners and can’t be bothered to even give lip service to safety. No mask. No hearing protection. No guard on the grinder. Waggling the tile around in space while cutting. All of it, and I mean ALL of it is so unnecessarily stupid. Don’t even get me started on his, ‘I probably invented circle cutting with a grinder’ line.

Comment: You had youtube for your rant why did you have to dump it here withiut adding anything to the topic?

Comment: You've asked more than enough questions here to know that you should [edit] the additional information into the question instead of burying it in the comments. Also, if the guy in a video is doing things without any regard to safety, then the other things he's doing should probably be questioned, as well.

Answer (score 1):

All utility boxes come with 2 holes (at least) for attaching a face plate - this is probably mentioned in somewhere in the NEC.   He was probably explaining something simple in a weird-complicated way.

The only extra you may need for tile is a box extender and even these aren't needed most of the time.

Comment: see here please https://youtu.be/aOxBqHNeOQ8?t=854 , he is also showing the cuts he is not going to cut because of that "special" box you can buy. "Link in the description" but I am not seeing the link hence the ask here

Answer (score 0):

Not a special box -- just a 2 piece cover plate.

Google "snap on cover plate". Leviton, Legrand all make them.

Most people just clip the cover plate screws shorter if the tile is in the way.

[Snap on cover plate](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Plus-1-Gang-Screwless-Snap-On-Decora-Wall-Plate-White-R72-80301-00W/100199643)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A light switch, duplex outlet, and GFCI outlet all mount to an electrical box using the same screw holes on the electrical box. The mounting screws for the faceplate for the light switch are roughly an inch from the edge of the electrical box. The mounting screw for the faceplate for the duplex outlet is in the center. The screws for the faceplate for a GFCI outlet are way on the edge and outside the perimeter of the electrical box. They will contact and possibly crack the tile where the youtuber  drew two "bumps" on his cutout. If you're installing a GFCI outlet you should cut out the two bumps that he drew or as Aloysius Defenestrate suggested cut the screws shorter. Now would be a good time to start shopping for switches and outlets so you account for that.